# How to fix for loop that seemingly takes forever to run but running each loop individually is quick?

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, runtime

When I run the code below for each individually loop to run functions on a subset of the main dataframe that corresponds to specific dates, it runs quickly. When I try to loop it, however, it seemingly runs forever. There are 60 loops to go through in total.

My goal is to create a new column (col3) for each subset of date and combine it all into a single dataframe again.

```
data = pd.read_csv("df.csv")
data.YYMM = data.YYMM.apply(pd.to_datetime)
dates = data.groupby(data.YYMM).sum().index.values
data1 = pd.DataFrame()
for i in dates:
    df1 = data[data.YYMM == i]
    df1 = df1.sort_values(by='col1', ascending=False)
    df1['col2'] = df1.col1 / sum(df1.col1)
    df1['col3'] = reweight(df1.col2, cap)
    data1 = data1.append(df1, ignore_index = True)
```

Would appreciate any help!

The reweights function:

```
def reweight(weights, cap):
    # Obtain constrained weights
    constrained_wts = np.minimum(cap, weights)
    # Locate all stocks with less than max weight
    nonmax = constrained_wts.ne(cap)
    # Calculate adjustment factor - this is proportional to original weights
    adj = ((1 - constrained_wts.sum()) *
            weights.loc[nonmax] / weights.loc[nonmax].sum())
    # Apply adjustment to obtain final weights
    constrained_wts = constrained_wts.mask(nonmax, weights + adj)
    # Repeat process in loop till conditions are satisfied
    while ((constrained_wts.sum() < 1) or
           (len(constrained_wts[constrained_wts > cap]) >=1 )):
        # Obtain constrained weights
        constrained_wts = np.minimum(cap, constrained_wts)
        # Locate all stocks with less than max weight
        nonmax = constrained_wts.ne(cap)
        # Calculate adjustment factor - this is proportional to original weights
        adj = ((1 - constrained_wts.sum()) *
            constrained_wts.loc[nonmax] / weights.loc[nonmax].sum())
        # Apply adjustment to obtain final weights
        constrained_wts = constrained_wts.mask(nonmax, constrained_wts + adj)
    return constrained_wts
```

Comment: Add a `print()` message at the top of every loop.  This way, at least, you can see what loop is taking up the time.

Answer (score 0):

A vital part of debugging code is adding logging so that you get an idea of what the state of the script is. I would start by adding some log calls in `reweight()` so that you can get an idea of where your time is getting spent.

For more information on logging, take a look at [Logging HOWTO in the Python Documentation.](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html) (Yes, you can just use `print()` if you want, but with logging it's easy to make it output the current time for each line by default). Make sure you add some idea of what is in your variables when you log so you can see just how much work is being performed in each iteration, and whether you might have a condition where you'll never satisfy the `while` condition.

Key places to log out would be at the start and end of the `while` loop, so you have an idea of how your exit conditions are moving with each iteration, and whether you just have a lot of iterations or if your iterations are slowing down.